# Array of Objects - Select Subset of Array Where Obj.Prop IN Array of Values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. For example's sake, let's say these objects have an id and a name:

```
var myObjectArray = [{id:1, name:'objOne'}, {id:2, name:'objTwo'}];
```

I would like to select a subset of this array, only containing objects where object id is in a an array of acceptable ids. So like this:

```
var subsetArray = _.where(myObjectArray , {id:1});
```

Except instead of the `obj.id=1` condition, I want to say object id is IN `[3,4,5]`

Is there a clean way to do this? (anything like lodash, underscore, or raw javascript work). Or do I forget underscore/lodash/etc adn just iterate through every element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in vanilla JS with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var results = myObjectArray.filter(o => ~[3,4,5].indexOf(o.id));
```

`filter` accepts a callback, which gets called with each item in the array. If the callback returns true, it includes that item and not if otherwise.

`indexOf` accepts a value and looks for the zero-based index of the value in the array if it exists in the array, or `-1` if otherwise.

`~` is a bitwise operator that turns `-1` to `0` (among the other things it does), making `-1` a falsy value for use in our filter callback.

In the above example, filter is accepting a callback in the form of an arrow function. To the left of `=>` is `o`, which is the value from the array at each iteration. To the right of `=>` is an expression. Arrow allow implicit return of the expression value. Parens are also optional for single-valued arrow functions.

A more verbose equivalent would be:

```
var results = myObjectArray.filter(function(o){
  return [3,4,5].indexOf(o.id) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: You are awesome, works: https://plnkr.co/edit/ybC6htRWaOB34ly4OFwt?p=preview Will come back to accept.

Comment: Also, I really appreciate the explanation itself - to be honest I didn't understand it when I saw the solution without the details.

Comment: Note that if you need to support IE, Safari, or older versions of Firefox and Chrome that don't support the arrow functions, you can use the slightly more verbose function expression syntax: `var results = myObjectArray.filter(function(o){return ~[3,4,5].indexOf(o.id);});`

Comment: @Joseph - can you comment on the syntax you are using for filter.  Specifically, I've never seen a JS lambda outside of the ES6 intros I've been looking over.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded explanation.  This is an excellent answer!